# Can a Bluetooth low energy device which is in slave role have multiple masters?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I wanted to know if the Link layer of the LE device is in slave role can have mulitple masters.
I know that master can have multiple slaves but can a slave have multiple masters ?

Answer (score 5):

from 1.2 Overview Of Bluetooth Low Energy Operation, Bluetooth v4.1 specs:

> Slaves are permitted to have physical links to more than one master at a time.

In the Bluetooth v4.0 specs:

> At this time, slaves are **not** permitted to have physical links to more than one master at a time.

Comment: Thanks Tim for the information. Maybe devices with latest 4.1 will include this feature as now 4.0 is present in devices.

Comment: I just checked the 4.0 specs and added to the answer...  Even though 4.1 devices are "permitted" to have multiple masters, I'm not sure how many devices would actually implement that.

Answer (score 0):

From Bluetooth Spec v5.4
Vol 1, Part A, General description, 1.2 Overview Of Bluetooth Low Energy Operation,

"Within a physical channel, a physical link is formed between devices. The
active physical link provides bidirectional packet transport between the Central
and Peripherals. Centrals may have physical links to more than one Peripheral
at a time and Peripherals may have physical links to more than one Central at
a time. A device may be Central and Peripheral in different piconets at the
same time. Role changes between a Central and Peripheral are not supported.
The advertising and periodic physical links provide a unidirectional packet
transport from the advertiser to a potentially unlimited number of scanners or
initiators."