# Automatic bluetooth connection to a certain device

Tags: bluetooth, windows-phone-8.1

I am working on an application (windows phone 8.1), which is the following: if my phone is already connected to a bluetooth device then it should connect in parralel to another device which is already paired("cc2541"). I would appreciate a little help with the coding.

My problem is i don't know how to connect to a device automatically. I only found code samples that are only scans and lists devices and it only connects when I touch the screen ( approve the connectivity ).

Comment: You cannot connect to an already paired device with your Windows Phone. A master can connect to various slaves, but a slave cannot connect to various masters unless you're using Bluetooth v4.1. Here is a link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006972/can-a-bluetooth-low-energy-device-which-is-in-slave-role-have-multiple-masters

Answer (score 2):

You can get the RSSI value (signal strength) for each device, then you can implement a dispatcherTimer, where you start the scanning as the timer starts and then connect to the closest device on a timeout.

This is a basic example of automatic connection establishment.